# There is a project that runs in the simulator without problems, but when installed on a device (iphone 7) crashes (when opened)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

help, please, I need your help. There is a project that runs in the simulator without problems, but when installed on a device (iphone 7) crashes (when opened). Xcode shows (1 pic). Log device shows (2 fig).

[1 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGedZ.png)

[2 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxqEI.png)

Comment: Are you using some framework like Facebook.If so, did you ask them ? There is an image missing or offloaded when needed. Can you check which this image is ?

Comment: How did you add AsyncDisplayKit? are you using Carthage?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "Embed & Sign" for AsyncDisplayKit. Now I have a different problem:
**"== 994 == Unable to find a memory range after restricting VM.
== 994 == AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/clang_compiler_rt/clang-1103.0.32.62/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_mac.cc:92 "((0 && "cannot place shadow after restricting vm"))! = (0) "(0x0, 0x0)
 "**

Answer (score 0):

close the address sanitizer options, or change another better device